# Lucee/ColdFusion - Locking session scope across a cluster and accessing session vars concurrently

Tags: session, coldfusion, cluster-computing, lucee, application.cfc

*This question applies to a Lucee 5.x application. I'm not sure if there are differences between how ACF and Lucee handle session scopes across a cluster.*

**Background:** I'm implementing an `autoLogin()` function in `application.cfc` - in `onRequestStart()` - that looks for a token that's stored in a cookie, and then uses it to authenticate the user. Once a token has been used, it gets replaced with a new value, and the cookie is updated. When a token is not found or doesn't work, the cookie is deleted. A session lock is used to prevent multiple concurrent requests from attempting to login the user, which would have unintended side effects.

All the core functionality for this works (on a single node), but I need to make it cluster-friendly. The cluster is already setup correctly (`this.sessionCluster = true;` in application.cfc, along with a shared Memcached instance that stores session data), and it works fine.

The main questions I have are: (referencing the code below)

1. The code below uses an exclusive session lock to prevent concurrent requests from executing the login code at the same time. **How would you replace the session lock below with one that locks the session across the whole cluster?**
2. The code below assumes that changes to session variables can be seen immediately. **Is this true when a session variable is changed on one node, and then a concurrent request on another node tries to access that same variable? If not, is there a way to refresh the session scope to ensure you're getting the latest?**

Below is the autoLogin() function: (works on a single node)

```
private void function autoLogin () {

    // multiple, concurrent requests could be hitting this on different nodes in the cluster

    // if we're already logged in, nothing to do
    if (session.isLoggedIn) {
        return;
    }

    // get the auth token if it exists
    var token = cookie.keyExists("auth") && isValid("uuid", cookie.auth) ? cookie.auth : "";
    if (token == "") {
        // if a token doesn't exists, nothing to do
        return;
    }

    // assertion: user is not logged in and an auth token exists
    // attempt to login using the token, but make sure that only one 
    // request does this at a time - wrap with an exclusive session lock

    // lock the session - how would you do this on a cluster?
    lock scope="session" type="exclusive" timeout="10" throwontimeout=false {
        // check if logged in again - another thread may have succeeded while this
        // thread was waiting for the lock to open
        if (!session.loggedIn) {
            // we can only call this once if user is not logged in!
            application.auth.loginWithToken(authToken=token);
        }
    }

} // autoLogin()
```

Comment: If you are using the builtin cluster session handling mechanisim (`this.sessionCluster`) I would hope that it handles this situation for you. What happens when you test it? FWIW, I think `this.sessionCluster` is Lucee only.

Comment: Hard to test these things on a single node... I would maybe be able to do it using docker.

Comment: Ha, yeah impossible. Sorry I thought you had a cluster already setup.

Comment: The app is cluster-enabled and I use it to hot swap servers when I need to do updates. What I am trying to achieve is being able to add servers to scale as needed. Right now we don’t need to scale but that will change soon.